# Uprgrading to Rails 4.1 getting error: ArgumentError: Unknown key: :order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, upgrade

i'm in the middle of my upgrade and am running into some problems.

Here is my error:

> /Users/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:71:in
>   `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: :order. Valid keys are:
>   :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name,
>   :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend,
>   :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type,
>   :inverse_of, :counter_cache, :join_table (ArgumentError)

Does it have something to do with my scopes? For example:

`scope :total_views, order('total_views DESC')`

or

`default_scope { order: :sort_order }`

or

`scope :recent, order: 'created_at desc'`

I have bunch of scopes that use order, what is going on?

Comment: I had this problem, and I think it has it's roots in acts_as_tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named scopes in Rails 4 take lambdas now instead of hashes. Within a lambda use the new query syntax and not the old hash syntax:

```
default_scope { order(:sort_order) } 

scope :total_views, -> { order('total_views DESC') }
scope :recent,      -> { order('created_at DESC') }
```

Read more about ActiveRecord querying: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Thanks! that seems to be working.  I tried looking trough the docs, but has the syntax for this changed as well?  `has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy, order: "created_at DESC"`

Comment: Yes that changed also: `has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy, -> { order('created DESC') }`. I suggest to  have a look at: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-active-record.

Answer (score 0):

Your scopes need to be in the form of a lambda.

`scope :total_views, -> { order('total_views DESC') }`

`default_scope -> { order: :sort_order }`

`scope :recent, -> { order: 'created_at desc' }`

Comment: I went through and fixed all of my scopes, and am still getting the same error.  How can I pinpoint the problem more directly?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded acts_as_tree to version 2.1.0, and the problem went away.